# SSH login gives different values for $PATH

Tags: shell, ssh, visual-studio-code, putty

I am connecting to the same Ubuntu server using the same username and key file.

When I login via Putty the `$PATH` variable looks like this:

```
echo $PATH
/home/csrhub/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/bin:/home/csrhub/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7@global/bin:/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.7/bin:/usr/share/rvm/bin:/home/csrhub/.rbenv/shims:/home/csrhub/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

When I login via VS Code (Remote-SSH: Connect to Host...) `$PATH` looks different:

```
~$ echo $PATH
/home/csrhub/.rbenv/bin:/home/csrhub/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin:/home/csrhub/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648@global/bin:/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin:/home/csrhub/.vscode-server/bin/26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/share/rvm/bin
```

And the Ruby version is different.

`whoami` prints the same on both (Putty and VS Code). I also run both `echo`'s in the same working directory.

`~/.bash_rc` seems to be loaded because the aliases defined there are recognized by both shells.

I would like to see the VS Code terminal `$PATH` to look the same as the one via Putty.

Do you know where the difference comes from?

*** EDIT ***

I found a difference when checking the shell type:

Running this command on VS Code:

```
shopt -q login_shell && echo 'Login shell' || echo 'Not login shell'
```

prints out:

> Not login shell

While running the same command on Putty prints out:

> Login shell

When I log in via the VS code terminal, like this:

`/bin/bash --login`, the $PATH variable and the behavior (between the two terminals) is the same. So the question is little bit different now: How to "force" the VS code terminal, to log in automatically upon connection?